# Vectorizing new text data

Tags: python, vectorization, text-mining, word-embedding, nlp

I have trained a `Word2vec` model on the "brown corpus".

I want to apply the vectorized words to a new text document, whose sentences I then want to cluster by way `Affinity Propagation`.

```
import gensim
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

sentences = brown.sents()
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
model.save('brown_model')

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('brown_model')
```

My text document contains a list of requests such as:

```
"I want to go to the store"

"I want the president to help me"

"Clean up my house"
```

My question is:

How can I apply the vectorized `Brown corpus` to my own text data for subsequent clustering purposes?

Comment: Apply in what way? What kinds of outputs do you expect?

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 I expect that the words in my text document will contain the same vectors that the brown corpus words contain, helping my clustering algorithm make sense of everything. Otherwise all words will be '1' away from each other, which is obviously not what I want as it doesn't represent the true meaning. In terms of clustering at the end: I expect some arbitrary number of clusters, each one containing closest phrases in the document, with one input being the representative nucleus in each cluster.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well the issue of the *subsequent clustering purposes* can be solve like:

```
words = set(brown.words())
print (len(words))
...
word_presented = words.intersection(model.vocab.keys())
```

take a look to [this article](https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/word2vec-embedding-using-gensim-and-nltk)

Comment: At what point am I applying it to my own new text document? Is it correct to say that the purpose of training a Word2Vec model is to then apply it to your own text data? Just like in Machine Learning one might train a model, and then use the model for a classification task on a new dataset; I am trying to use the vectors associated with the trained model on my own text data. I then want to cluster the data, but that is not the locus of the question, just some context to help people understand what I'm going for. I'm mostly wondering how to vectorize my own data with this model.

Comment: I don't understand your issue is too generalized in your comment.